# Weebly CSS editing nav-menu

Tags: css

I'm trying to make some nav menu items non-clickable if they have sub categories. I figured out how to do it for parent items but I'm have trouble with child items -making them non-clickable if they branch to lesser categories.

```
`enter code here`#nav-wrap .wsite-nav-0 a, .wsite-nav-1 a {pointer-events: none;};
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your HTML? Context is always good.

Comment: <body class='  wsite-theme-light wsite-page-index'>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="bg-wrapper">
  <div id="header">
   
  <div id="navigation"><ul class='wsite-menu-default'><li id='pg466893405210374863'><a href='/about.html'>About</a><div class='wsite-menu-wrap' style='display:none'><ul class='wsite-menu'><li id='wsite-nav-769587679802207120'><a href='/instructors.html' ><span class='wsite-menu-title'>Instructors</span></a></li>

Comment: Instructors are a sub menu under 'About'. I'd like to make 'Instructors' non-clickable for example if I wanted to branch off even further.

Comment: You want the instructors link to be not clickable even though it has a `href` attribute that looks like a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is sounds like what you are looking for is a `parent selector`, such a selector [does not currently exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Some options:

- Set a class for those you dont want to be clickable. Simple and to the point.
- Use the href attibute as part of the selector, and set href="#".

  ```
  <a href="#">Instructors [Other stuff here]</a>

  /*CSS*/
  #navigaion a[href="#"] {pointer-events: none;}
  ```
- Finally re-think. I always try to have a page for everything in my menus. Have a general instructors page with a paragraph or two about the group, then links to the indidvidual instructots.